# Why is there an extra letter appearing with screen buffers

Tags: c++, winapi, console

So I tried making a basic game for testing movement with console. I decided to use screen buffers, but when I compile and run the c++ code the letter a appears with the player (character #)
Here's the code:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int width = 50, height = 20;
int main()
{
    wchar_t *screen = new wchar_t[width * height];
    HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
    DWORD bytesWritten = 0;
    int x = width / 2, y = height / 2;
    while (true) {
        screen[width * height - 1] = '\0';
        for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) screen[i] = L' ';
        if (GetAsyncKeyState('W') & 1) y--;
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState('S') & 1) y++;
        if (GetAsyncKeyState('A') & 1) x--;
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState('D') & 1) x++;
        // keep the character inside
        if (x < 0) x = 0;
        else if (x > width-1) x = width-1;
        if (y < 0) y = 0;
        else if (y > height - 1) y = height - 1;
        wsprintf(&screen[width * y + x], L"#");
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, screen, width * height, { 0,0 }, &bytesWritten);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running it looks like this:
[image]

I use visual studio 2017.

Why does the letter a appear?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I compiled your code, but there is no letter a.  My compiler is vs2019.

Comment: Use " " instead of  "#"  to see if a appears. By the way, VS2017 cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT still appears

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Try `sprintf` instead of `wsprintf` and try `L"#\0"` instead of ``L"#"`` and tell us what happens

Comment: `screen[width * height - 1] = '\0';` puts a null terminator at the *very end* of the `screen` buffer, but then `for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) screen[i] = L' ';`  overwrites that null terminator with a space character. Then `wsprintf(&screen[width * y + x], L"#");` will insert its own null terminator after the written `'#'` character, but that doesn't matter since `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, screen, width * height, { 0,0 }, &bytesWritten);` writes the *entire* `screen` buffer as-is whether it contains a null terminator or not.